# How to check if product has a specific product attribute in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-taxonomy

I would like to identify if a product has an attribute or not. For example:

```
if (product has attribute 'pa_color')
{
    //do something
}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Hey, sorry I forgot to mark it as the correct answer. Your answer worked for me thank you.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You simply can use the `WC_Product` method `get_attribute()` this way:

```
// (If needed) Get an instance of the WC_Product Object from the product ID
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

// Get the product attribute value(s)
$color = $product->get_attribute('pa_color');

// if product has attribute 'pa_color' value(s)
if( ! empty( $color ) ){
    // do something
} else {
    // No product attribute is set for this product
}
```