# WooCommerce: check if product has attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to append text to products that cointain the attribute "pa_sprog" value "dansk"

I am working from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712333/how-to-check-if-product-has-a-specific-product-attribute-in-woocommerce) post
this is what I have so far:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'flag1' );    
function flag1() {
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );

    // Get the product attribute value
    $sprog = $product->get_attribute('pa_sprog');

    // if product has attribute 'sprog' value(s)
    if( $sprog="dansk" ){
        echo '<div class="">"Dansk!"</div>';
    } else {
        // Engelsk
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give it a try this way, I left the code to debug, so that you can view the WC_Product_Attribute Object in detail. Afterwards you can safely remove this

```php
function flag1() {
    global $product;

    // for debug purposes, place in comment tags or delete this code
    $product_attributes = $product->get_attributes();
    echo '<pre>', print_r($product_attributes, 1), '</pre>';

    // Get the product attribute value
    $sprog = $product->get_attribute('pa_sprog');

    // if product has attribute 'sprog' value(s)
    if( $sprog == "dansk" ) {
        echo '<div class="">Dansk!</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div class="">Engelsk!</div>';
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'flag1' );
```