# How do I hide WooCommerce products with a given attribute based on user role?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a "**Wholesaler**" user. I am looking for a way to hide products with a given attribute "**nonwh**".

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide any code, but you could probably user something with the `wp_get_current_user()` function. and the `wc_get_product()` function.

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'Wholesaler', (array) $user->roles ) ) {

// This checks too see if the user has the role of Wholesaler.

}
```

And maybe wrap the above around the `wc_get_product()` function.

```
    $products = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    
    $nonwh = $product->get_attribute('nonwh'); 
    
        if( ! empty( $nonwh ) ){
            
// Do nothing if product has the nonwh attribute

        } else {
        //Show Products
    }
```

This is a function found in an answer here:
[How to check if product has a specific product attribute in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49712333/how-to-check-if-product-has-a-specific-product-attribute-in-woocommerce)

This should be a good start to what you are trying to accomplish.